# coldfusion ignore undefined variables

Tags: coldfusion

if I use

```
<cfoutput>#somevariable#</cfoutput>
```

and `somevariable` is not defined I get an error, how can I prevent the error from occourring?
is there a simple way of implementing a conditional that doesn't require a bunch of extra lines?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<cfparam name="somevariable" default="" />
```

If you're on cf 9 you can use a ternary operation, but cfparam is more 'best practicey'.

```
#isDefined("somevariable") ? somevariable : 'default string'#
```

Comment: If you're going to use the ternary operator, I'd recommend `structkeyexists( scope, "somevariable" )` rather than `isdefined`. It's quicker to search only the scope in which you expect the variable to be defined, and it prevents CF from retrieving a variable from a different scope. If you do use `isdefined`, at least provide the scope with the variable (which the OP should have done as well).

Answer (score 1):

You can test for the variable

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfif isDefined("somevariable")>
        #somevariable#
    <cfelse>
        handle default scenario here
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

or you could use inline conditional

```
<cfoutput>
    #IIF(isDefined("somevariable"),de(somevariable),de(""))#
</cfoutput>
```